# What would a Laravel deploy script look like?

Tags: php, laravel, deployment

I'm using **Buddy Works** to deploy my project to a server.

When creating a pipeline to deploy my Laravel project, I'm asked to enter deployment actions; this is where I'm stuck.

So far, I have set it to run the following `composer` commands:

```
composer validate
composer install
```

Because this is usually what I do when running my project locally. But I understand that I also need to run Apache and such (I use WAMP so it sorts all that for me).

I've searched on Google and all I got was `composer install`. Is this all I need to do or is there more?

Prior to using deployment tools, I used to upload files directly to the server, so CI/CD or other DevOps duties are very new to me.

Comment: what platform are you deploying to? (eg: AWS)

Comment: @AngadDubey DigitalOcean

Comment: is apache/php already setup on digital ocean?

Comment: @AngadDubey I don't think so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good idea to reload php as well as migrate new tables :)

```
 composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader
 echo "" | sudo -S service php7.3-fpm reload
 php artisan migrate --force
```

If you're using DigitalOcean and you have $12 to spare you could use ready tools such as [Laravel Forge](https://forge.laravel.com/) :)